# Readirect after Created to custom url in React admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have Campaigns Resource, each campaign has a number of URLs. I'd like to redirect after URL Create to the URL of Campaign edit. (There's a list of linked URLs).

```
export default () => {

    const campaign_id = ....;

    const redirect2 = (basePath, id, data) => `/#/campaign/${campaign_id}`;
    const redirect =  `/#/campaign/${campaign_id}`;

    
    return <Create redirect={redirect}>
        <SimpleForm> 
            <h2>New URL for campaign #{campaign_id}</h2>
            <TextInput source="url"  />
            <NumberInput source="weight" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
}
```

I tried both string and function as the parameter of the redirect property, but neither works.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try like this: `/campaign/${campaign_id}`

Comment: What you want to achieve isn't clear, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The comment of MaxAlex worked. Strange thing, in href attribute of a Link React requires /#/ prefix.